# Overriding method that has no access modifier with protected access modifier

Tags: java, overriding, access-modifiers

When you override methods you are not allowed to reduce the visibility of the inherited method. According to the following table, `protected` is more accessible than `no modifier`:

```
            | Class | Package | Subclass | World
————————————+———————+—————————+——————————+———————
public      |  y    |    y    |    y     |   y
————————————+———————+—————————+——————————+———————
protected   |  y    |    y    |    y     |   n
————————————+———————+—————————+——————————+———————
no modifier |  y    |    y    |    n     |   n
————————————+———————+—————————+——————————+———————
private     |  y    |    n    |    n     |   n

y: accessible
n: not accessible
```

But when I try to override `f()` (see SubClass) then I get the error:

**Cannot reduce the visibility of the inherited method from MyInterface.**

The method in MyInterface has no access modifier and the one in SubClass is protected, so more accessible. What am I missing here?

```
public interface MyInterface {
  void f();
}

public abstract class MyClass {
  protected abstract void f();
}

public class SubClass extends MyClass implements MyInterface{
   protected void f() { }
}
```

Comment: You don't *override* interface methods. You *implement* them.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - [jls jargon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1) - an instance method mC declared in class C, *overrides* another method mI declared in a superinterface, iff ...

Comment: @bayou.io: Interesting, I have never heard it put that way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Methods in interfaces [implicitly](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/interfaceDef.html) have the access modifier of `public`. So when you implement it with `protected`, it is a weaker access modifier.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder That's a bit of a nitpick since you still use `@Override` when you implement them.

Comment: @Amila Is this only for interfaces or are there any other cases where no modifier = public ?

Comment: @Dongo Only in interfaces, as far as I know

Comment: @ajb: Do you? Oh, hey, look, as of Java 1.6 (so, some years back), you do: http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=5008260

Comment: @Amila: I was referring to the question rather than your answer, just for clarity. (In fact, I wrote that comment before you added your second sentence.) No criticism intended at all. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Methods in interfaces are implicitly marked `public` and not `default`

Answer (score 2):

From Java [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1):

> The access modifier (§6.6) of an overriding or hiding method must
>   provide at least as much access as the overridden or hidden method, as
>   follows:
>
> 1. If the overridden or hidden method is public, then the overriding or hiding method must be public; otherwise, a compile-time error
>      occurs.
> 2. If the overridden or hidden method is protected, then the overriding or hiding method must be protected or public; otherwise, a
>      compile-time error occurs.
> 3. If the overridden or hidden method has default (package) access, then the overriding or hiding method must not be private; otherwise, a
>      compile-time error occurs.

The methods in an interface are by default `public`. So you cannot override/hide this method using any modifier other than `public`.

Answer (score 0):

On a learner scale in java, it's a good question. But you have to remember that, there are default and implicit access modifiers , like interface in this case that is implicitly `public` **by default**.

```
public interface MyInterface {
  void f();
}
```

and

```
public interface MyInterface {
  public void f();
}
```

both are same implicitly. Interfaces are designed in such a way that their behavior is exposed publicly.

Answer (score 0):

In java Interface, 
all the methods are public.
all the variables are public static final.(constants)

Answer (score 0):

Interface methods are born with **public**

Give

```
protected void f();
```

Or

```
private void f();
```

In MyInterface and see what you get.